# Scraping data from .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from a .aspx page, and I wanted to know if there was any way to do this apart from using selenium to select all possible options and click the submit button.
I tried looking at the network section but did not understand where the data is coming from. Could anyone help me out?

Here is a link to the page: 
https://www.lgindiasocial.com/microsites/brand-store-web-five/locate.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way than simulating option changes and click event.

---

Reason:

The page is rendered with **ASP.NET Ajax (WebForms)**. This was Microsoft implementation of Ajax *many, many years back*. Most people(if not all) consider Webforms obslete. The section under your consideration uses, [UpdatePanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8)

> Enables sections of a page to be partially rendered without a postback.

It *does not return* an `xml` or `json` as one normally expect from an AJAX request. Instead, it returns the new rendered html and place it inside the `UpdatePanel`.

The request will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the response will be `text/plain`. It also send the `ViewState ([What Is View State And How It Works In ASP.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/)).

If you view source, you will understand that the UpdatePanel returns new html for the content inside `<div id="UpdatePanel1">` for each `xhr` `HTTP POST` request in the network tab.